# fork(): Number of child processes created

Tags: c, fork

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
int main() 
{ 
  int pid =  fork(); 
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {  
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        fork();
        printf("fork\n");
    } 
  }    
return 0; 
}
```

I think it should generate a total number of 6 child processes. But it is not so. Why

Comment: How many does it create and how do you count them?

Comment: If you count by the number of times the `fork` is printed...? **when is it printed**? If the number 5 is difficult, why not try **1** first?

Answer (score 3):

### Explanation

`fork()` creates a *duplicate* process that continues to run the code from whereever it was called in parallel with the parent. In parent fork() returns child PID, and in child it returns zero - other than that new processes are identical but are copies of each other - setting a variable in one does not affect the other.

Normally after `fork()` you check its return to see if this copy of your program is a child or a parent and act accordingly.

### Corrected code

So, if you were aiming to create 6 child processes (plus one parent) you should have done something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
int main() 
{ 

  printf("Hello from parent, my PID is %d\n", getpid());
  for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
  {  
    int pid = fork(); 
    if (pid == 0)
    {
       printf("Hello from child, my PID is %d\n", getpid());
       return 0;
    }
    printf("Parent created child with PID=%d\n", pid);
  }    
return 0; 
}
```

and the output on my system is:

```
Hello from parent, my PID is 26354
Parent created child with PID=26355
Hello from child, my PID is 26355
Parent created child with PID=26356
Parent created child with PID=26357
Parent created child with PID=26358
Hello from child, my PID is 26356
Parent created child with PID=26359
Parent created child with PID=26360
Hello from child, my PID is 26357
Hello from child, my PID is 26358
Hello from child, my PID is 26359
Hello from child, my PID is 26360
```

Notice that each child prints out `Hello from child...` message and then exits immediately by `return`ing from `main()`.

### Mistakes

- Your code does that check wrong so spawned children don't just exit - they continue creating more children of their own, and their children proceed to do the same.

  - You should have assigned `pid = fork()` each time, not just the first time.
  - If your child is done, it's recommended to let it quit right away by calling `return` rather then letting it continue to loop through your program and wrapping parts of it in `if (pid==0)` checks - this may lead to further mistakes
  - Your parent creates the first child (before the loop) and receives non-zero `pid` so it still goes through subsequent loop but does nothing else - the first child does all the work.
- Furthermore, `fork\n` is printed twice each time `fork()` is called because both a parent and a child do it right after each (except the "before-the-loop" first) child is created - probably not what you intended.

### Code analysis

Let's see what the code does.

I'll number the processes arbitrarily, process #0 is the original parent.

```
int pid =  fork();
```

Process #0 creates process #1. In child (#1) `pid = 0`, in parent (#0) it is non-zero.

Because following code checks that `pid` is `0`:

```
if(pid == 0)
{
    fork();
    printf("fork\n");
}
```

... process #0 loops 5 times but does nothing, prints out nothing and eventually exits.

Because `pid` is not written to anymore and is not checked, for process #1 and all subsequent processes this loop looks like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{  
      fork();
      printf("fork\n");
}    
return 0;
```

Following happens in parallel, ordering is arbitrary:

- Now process#1 creates five children - #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, printing out `fork\n` each time, and eventually exits.
- Process#2 starts where process #1 left off creating it, with `i=0`, right before `printf` so it prints out `fork\n` and proceeds to print out the message 4 more times and create 4 more children of its own (#7, #8, #9, #10) and eventually exits
- Process#3 starts where process #1 left off creating it, with `i=1`, right before `printf` so it prints out `fork\n` and proceeds to create 3 more children of its own, printing out the message 3 more times (#11, #12, #13) and eventually exits
- Process#4 creates 2 processes (#14, #15), prints 3 messages
- Process#5 creates 1 process (#16), prints 2 messages
- Process#6 is left off with `i=4` so it prints out a message and exits.
- Process#7 (that was created by a second child) is left off in the same situation as process #3 so it prints the message 4 times and creates 3 more children of its own...

... at this point I'll probably stop, you should already see where this is going.

This is the output of your program after I added some logging to it. I also sorted output a little bit - because it all happens in parallel it is hard to keep track otherwise:

```
Process 27939 is the original parent
Process 27939 created process 27940 <--- this is the 'out-of-loop' child
Process 27939 finished executing
Process 27940 created process 27942
Process 27940: fork
Process 27940 created process 27943
Process 27940: fork
Process 27940 created process 27944
Process 27940: fork
Process 27940 created process 27945
Process 27940: fork
Process 27940 created process 27946
Process 27940: fork
Process 27940 finished executing
Process 27942: fork
Process 27942 created process 27954
Process 27942: fork
Process 27942 created process 27955
Process 27942: fork
Process 27942 created process 27956
Process 27942: fork
Process 27942 created process 27957
Process 27942: fork
Process 27942 finished executing
Process 27943: fork
Process 27943 created process 27958
Process 27943: fork
Process 27943 created process 27959
Process 27943: fork
Process 27943 created process 27960
Process 27943: fork
Process 27943 finished executing
Process 27944: fork
Process 27944 created process 27961
Process 27944: fork
Process 27944 created process 27962
Process 27944: fork
Process 27944 finished executing
Process 27945: fork
Process 27945 created process 27963
Process 27945: fork
Process 27945 finished executing
Process 27946: fork
Process 27946 finished executing
Process 27954: fork
Process 27954 created process 27970
Process 27954: fork
Process 27954 created process 27971
Process 27954: fork
Process 27954 created process 27972
Process 27954: fork
Process 27954 finished executing
Process 27955: fork
Process 27955 created process 27978
Process 27955: fork
Process 27955 created process 27979
Process 27955: fork
Process 27955 finished executing
Process 27956: fork
Process 27956 created process 27981
Process 27956: fork
Process 27956 finished executing
Process 27957: fork
Process 27957 finished executing
Process 27958: fork
Process 27958 created process 27980
Process 27958: fork
Process 27958 created process 27982
Process 27958: fork
Process 27958 finished executing
Process 27959: fork
Process 27959 created process 27983
Process 27959: fork
Process 27959 finished executing
Process 27960: fork
Process 27960 finished executing
Process 27961: fork
Process 27961 created process 27984
Process 27961: fork
Process 27961 finished executing
Process 27962: fork
Process 27962 finished executing
Process 27963: fork
Process 27963 finished executing
Process 27970: fork
Process 27970 created process 28002
Process 27970: fork
Process 27970 created process 28003
Process 27970: fork
Process 27970 finished executing
Process 27971: fork
Process 27971 created process 28004
Process 27971: fork
Process 27971 finished executing
Process 27972: fork
Process 27972 finished executing
Process 27978: fork
Process 27978 created process 28006
Process 27978: fork
Process 27978 finished executing
Process 27979: fork
Process 27979 finished executing
Process 27980: fork
Process 27980 created process 28008
Process 27980: fork
Process 27980 finished executing
Process 27981: fork
Process 27981 finished executing
Process 27982: fork
Process 27982 finished executing
Process 27983: fork
Process 27983 finished executing
Process 27984: fork
Process 27984 finished executing
Process 28002: fork
Process 28002 created process 28043
Process 28002: fork
Process 28002 finished executing
Process 28003: fork
Process 28003 finished executing
Process 28004: fork
Process 28004 finished executing
Process 28006: fork
Process 28006 finished executing
Process 28008: fork
Process 28008 finished executing
Process 28043: fork
Process 28043 finished executing
```